# Square brackets in CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

What does it mean when something between square brackets in CSS? E.g.

`input[type="radio"]`

Comment: What a way to welcome new users. Sheesh. Took like 10 seconds to use Google Translate. Lets at least give the new guys a small chance. Everyone was a noob once.

Comment: [Attribute Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines uses square brackets to name grid lines. I don't understand how that works. They are not attribute selectors, I think.

Answer (score 22):

It's an attribute selector in CSS

> `E[foo="warning"]`    Matches any E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly equal to "warning".

more on http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 11):

Square brackets are [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) syntax.

Your (complete) example means "Select elements of type *input* which have a *type* attribute with the value *radio*" e.g. `<input type="radio">`

Answer (score 4):

This is an attribute selector. It selects elements that have the specified attribute. You can find out more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors

In your example: `input[type="radio"]`

This would match an element that looked like this:

```
<input type='radio'>
```

The selector you've given in the question means it would need all three words: The element name 'input', the attribute 'type' and the value for that attribute being 'radio'.

Browser compatibilty: This is a standard selector that is available in all browsers in common use. The only browser you may need to worry about that doesn't support it is IE6. [See here](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) for compatibility charts for this and other CSS selectors.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS attribute selector that will only select inputs with the type set to radio, that is, it will select all of the radio buttons.
[Here's](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) an article explaining it a bit more.