# Brackets as CSS selector in chrome Chrome DevTools

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I was debugging my UI using Chrome DevTools and recently came across brackets as selector for styling.

Could anyone explain what kind of CSS selector is this:

```
    [data-openweb-style-wrapper][data-openweb-style-wrapper] .spcv_conversation-header .spcv_info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

[image]

I'm confused with this part, I don't exactly understand, is this even a part of CSS or some bloat added by the chrome?

```
    [data-openweb-style-wrapper][data-openweb-style-wrapper]
```

Comment: Just search *css square brackets selector* or something. Like here: [Square brackets in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041149/square-brackets-in-css)

Comment: It's the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). It matches all elements with a data-openweb-style-wrapper attribute. As to why it appears twice, I can only imagine it's generated automatically as [data-openweb-style-wrapper][data-openweb-style-wrapper] and [data-openweb-style-wrapper] do the same thing